# remove lines from a file by using an index array

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to remove some specific lines from a file. I've an index array that keeps which lines will be removed.  I've used the following command for this issue.  But, it removes only the one line which is pointed to by the first member of the index array. I can't delete the rest of the lines.  Is there any problem with the command?

```
**sed -i ${index_array}'d' $file_name**
```

Comment: Can you plop your sed statement in a for loop, going through each item in index_array?

Comment: for $i in ${index_array} do sed -i ${i}d filename done

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed & BASH):

```
sed -i ''"${index_array[*]/%/d;}"'' file
```

or:

```
sed -i -f - <<<"${index_array[@]/%/d;}" file
```

or:

```
echo "${index_array[@]/%/d;}" | sed -i -f - file
```

Comment: The empty strings (`''`) at the start and end of that first script are doing nothing and could be removed.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
for i in "${index_array[@]}"
do
    sed -i "${i}d" "$filename"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in "${index_array[@]}"; do sed_script+=" -e '/^$line\$/d'"; done
sed -i "$sed_script" file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nums=$(echo ${index_array[@]} | sed 's/ /\\|/')

sed = input_file | sed '
{
N
s/\n/ /
}
' | sed "/^$nums /d" | sed 's/^[0-9]* //'
```