# Double single quotes in a sed command

Tags: bash, sed

I was trying to remove lines that had an element already seen in them (an ID) while keeping the first that appeared with sed. I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530438/remove-lines-from-a-file-by-using-an-index-array) but it was not explained at all and I am struggling to understand it.

Example of test.txt (IDs will not always be numerically sorted but duplicates will follow each others) :

```
1
2
3
3
4
4
4
5
6
7
7
```

Result wanted :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

The code:

```bash
#creates array of Ids
mapfile -t id_array < <(cut -f1 test.txt)
#loops over IDs
for (( i=0; i < ${#id_array[@]}; i++ )) 
do
     prev=$(($i-1))
     #compares each ID with the previous one, if same then adds it to index
     if (( ${id_array[$prev]} == ${id_array[$i]} ))
     then 
          index_array+=($i)
     fi
done
#line I dont fully understand, removes lines from array
sed -i ''"${index_array[*]/%/d;}"'' test.txt
```

The last line deletes inplace the  lines indexed in the arrray. `[*]` expands all values in a single word (`[@]` would not work as it expands each value in its in own word). The `/%/` replaces whitespaces with `d;` with [parameters expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). But I completely fail to understand the `''` on each side. Just one simple quote does not not work. Why ?

EDIT: it came to me that its was to keep the first (internal) `'` to keep the sed expression in single quotes as required, true ?

Comment: Why not just use `uniq test.txt`?

Comment: They serve no purpose. As for your task, it looks like you want to "uniq based on a single column", something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76605540

Comment: `''` is an empty string. So this is simply concatenating two empty strings around the `sed` argument, which has no effect.

Comment: @Barmar My file has other columns. Each line might have the same ID but will have different values in other columns. I did not include more information because it was not relevant.

Comment: Then `awk` would probably be easier.

Comment: @jqurious I do not want just 'uniq' but the first occurence. There are other columns which will have different values even if they have the same value at the first column.

Comment: `awk '!a[$1] { a[$1] = 1; print }' test.txt`

Comment: @Barmar I'll keep that solution, really need to learn awk. Indeed the quotes have no effect, it went above my head. Solved !

Comment: Regarding [My file has other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77017890/double-single-quotes-in-a-sed-command#comment135773319_77017890) - please post examples that look like your real data. If your real data has multiple columns then don't provide an example that only has 1 column, show at least 2 and preferably 3.

Comment: `awk '!a[$1] { a[$1] = 1; print }' test.txt` idiomatically is `awk '!seen[$1]++' test.txt` but [there's a better way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77032374/1745001).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct awk solution for this is:

```
awk '$1 != prev{print} {prev=$1}' test.txt
```

The above stores almost nothing in memory, just 2 `$1`s at a time. If you did `awk '!seen[$1]++' test.txt`, on the other hand, you'd get the same output but then you'd have to store all unique `$1` values in memory together and so YMMV if your input is massive.

Comment: This is not really a good solution, though.  If you only want to delete duplicate lines that are next to each other in the text, this will work.  But if that's the problem you are trying to solve, then `uniq` is a better tool than `awk`.  The standard awk approach is useful because it handles non-contiguous duplicates.

Comment: @WilliamPursell You can't isolate a field using `uniq` unless it happens to be the last field and you have GNU `uniq`, The IS the "standard" awk approach for the problem the OP has of needing to not print contiguous dups in a specific column of their input that their data is sorted on.

Comment: ahh, I had not noticed that detail.

Comment: Thank you for the different answer, `awk '!seen[$1]++'` worked indeed, but having a more memory-efficient solution is nice !

Comment: You're welcome. It's not just more memory-efficient, not using an array will also be much faster if you have a large input file due to the way array memory is allocated and then reallocated as it approaches it's previous allocation.

Answer (score 0):

This question has nothing to do with `sed`, and really nothing to do with removing duplicates from the input.  Instead, it is just a question about shell quoting.  In general, when the shell sees a line like:

```
cmd ''text"more text"'and $more $text'"even $more text"
```

it has to process that line to decide what to do.  One of the very early steps in the process is "quote removal", where the shell handles quotes.  Any text in single quotes is treated verbatim, while text in double quotes is subject to parameter expansion (eg, variable replacement).  Also, both forms of quotes prevent word splitting (aka "field splitting", which can be thought of as the processes of splitting the string to produce multiple arguments).  In other words, given the above line (and assuming the variable `more` has the value `foo`), the argument passed to `cmd` will be the string `textmore textand $more $texteven foo text`  Notice that this produces very different behavior that invoking the command: `cmd textmore textand $more $texteven foo text`, which the shell would parse and (if the variable `texteven` is unset) then invoke `cmd` with the 5 arguments `textmore`, `textand`, `foo`, `foo`, and `text`

Adjacent strings are just concatenated, and `''` is expanded to the empty string.  The primary purpose of quoting is to prevent parameter expansion and to prevent word splitting.  (eg, in the above example, `cmd` gets only one argument instead of having each word split into a separate argument.  This is why invocations of `sed` often have their argument quoted with single quotes.)

In this particular case, the line:

```
sed -i ''"${index_array[*]/%/d;}"'' test.txt
```

after quote removal looks like:

```
sed -i foo test.txt
```

where `foo` is the expansion of the parameter `${index_array[*]/%/d;}` (it is expanded because it is in double quotes), which is just a textual substitution on the each of the entries in the array.  eg, if the array is `a`, `b`, `c`, then `foo` is the string `ad; bd; cd;`  which is a pretty clumsy way to construct an argument to pass to `sed`.  My guess is that the duplicated single quotes are there because the author held the belief that an argument to `sed` must always be in single quotes, which seems to be a commonly held (but incorrect) belief.  Two adjacent single quotes are expanded by the shell to the empty string, and concatenating the empty string to a string is a no-op.

Shell quoting is a vast subject, and the above description intentionally omits many details.  A good general rule is "use double quotes if you want variables to be expanded, use single quotes if you don't".  That rule will solve 95% of issues related to shell quoting.